# How to insert HTML markup with PHP content in JS

Tags: php, jquery

I mean that inside HTML  this does not work when I try to add such a string to js `$('.msg_content').append('<span><?php echo $item; ?></span>');`

Comment: Look in to AJAX

Comment: and without it is impossible

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is not well-written and this may decrease your chance of getting an answer now and for the future questions, please check this page for tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How is this not working? What do you see when you look at the rendered HTML source; "code"? Are you running this off a webserver with an HTTP protocol or as `file:///` directly into your browser? What is the value and origin of `$item`? What is the file's extension it's running as? Your question lacks a LOT of detail. @K-sS-k

Answer (score -2):

Probably would be best to rename your .html page into a .php page. 
This would resolve your issue I think.

Also side note you can use

```
<?= $item; ?> instead of <?php echo $item; ?>
```

Provide some additional information for additional help.

Comment: `.html` files *can* be run as PHP.